# Strip millisecond in Teradata

Tags: teradata

What is the easiest way to strip milliseconds from a timestamp field. I am extracting data from a table and I want the data to be in YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss format. but I am getting ss.ssssss in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following method should work:

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     , CAST(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS CHAR(19)) AS TIMESTAMP(0));
```